# Manipulating form text across classes

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I'm having a humdinger of a time getting this to work, and I feel like it's so simple...

I have 2 classes, form1.cs and logic.cs

On form1, I have a private variable "output", with public property Output that I can set the value. I also have a public method to set the contents of textbox1.Text (keeping textbox1 private).

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string output;

        public string Output
        {
            get { return output; }
            set
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    output += value;
            }
        }

        public void SetTextbox1(string value)
        {
            textbox1.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

On logic, I have instances where I'm trying to change the variable on form1 to update the textbox1

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    class logic
    {
        public void Info(string imagePath, string mountDir)
        {
            mountDir = "C:\\mount"

            try
            {
                DismImageInfoCollection imageInfo = DismApi.GetImageInfo(mountDir)
                form1.Output = imageInfo.ToString();
                form1.SetTxtOutput(form1.Output);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting error messages in the last 2 lines of try that say:

`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'form1.Output'`

If I change Output, SetTxtOutput(), and output to static, it complains because textbox1 isn't static as well.

What is the proper way of manipulating textbox Text values across classes without setting the textbox to public and manipulating it directly?

Comment: I think that what compiler is saying is that form1 is declared as static. Can you show us the form1 declaration / initialization

Comment: 1 - where are you making the instance of form1? 2 - your form1 class code you have posted is incorrect - it just shows the namespace element and then the class contents

Comment: You're right - I missed the declaration of Form1. It is autogenerated from VS2015 (i.e., the class that the visual designer uses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually pass the form1 object to the logic class I.e.

```
 //default constructor
 Logic(form1 Form)
 {
     Form.output;
 }
```

The reason that you are getting the error is because winforms creates a new class for each form, and to access elements of a class without instantiating it those elements need to have the static keyword.

As a side note if you just create a new instance of form1 (`form1 form = new form1()`) this creates a new instance of the form and not the displayed form.

Comment: I wouldn't name your variable `Form`.  That's very confusing.

Comment: It honestly doesn't matter I just am another case of engineering naming and since there is only one form... `form1 Form`

Comment: Not only confusing, but you are ignoring accepted [naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx).  Consistency matters.

Comment: OK fair enough, I've only really worked on my own projects so I haven't really needed to keep things consistent, however whenever I'm working on a larger project I tend to use Hungarian notation more often

Comment: That worked. It took a minute because I was only seeing the partial answer and not the full context. I changed my info method parameters to `public static void Info(string imagePath, string mountDir, Form1 f)` and then referencing `try { f.Output = imageInfo.ToString(); }` and etc instead of `Form1.Output`. In Form1, when calling the method, I now call `logic.Info(GetTxtMountDir(), this);` and there's no compile errors. I'm now getting a different error message on catch (8007007A), but I'm sure that's related to the dll I'm using.