# How to call a class containing a certain string from a different form C#

Tags: c#

```
public void y()
    {string[] names = new string[3]
    {"A","B","C"};
    Random r = new Random();
    string xx = (names[r.Next(0, 4)]);
    }
```

sorry if there is already a post for this, I really don't know what to search for.
(above is my class) and(below main form)
So lets say I would like to call **string xx** from my main form,i've tried the following

```
        Class1 cs = new Class1();
        richTextBox1.Text = cs.y.xx;
```

so my problem lies at the main form for calling the string **xx**
what am I missing?
thanks!! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manipulating form text across classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090633/manipulating-form-text-across-classes)

Comment: You might want to search for and learn about [declarations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691107%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). And probably it is worth to read the whole chapter of Basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

declare the string outside the method as a public string.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string xx { get; set; }

    public void y()
    {
        string[] names = new string[3] {"A","B","C"};
        Random r = new Random();
        this.xx = (names[r.Next(0, 4)]);
    }
}
```

and in your other class

```
Class1 cs = new Class1();
richTextBox1.Text = cs.xx;
```